# Find out when file is added to folder

Tags: c#, file, directory

I would like to know if it is possible to find out when a file is added to a folder in C#. I know you can see the time of creation and many other things in the FileInfo, but nok when it was added.

Comment: I don't actually know any C#, but generally I know that such information isn't stored in the file system so shouldn't be available. The only option I can think of is to take "snapshots" of a folder, checking what files are in there at that time. Then, you come back and take another "snapshot" and compare the two, and see if your file has been added in the mean time. You would have to decide on a suitable interval between snapshots.

Comment: Do you mean to find out when the file was added to a folder retrospectively or to be notified when it happens (as per the FileSystemWatcher)?

Comment: I think I will go for the "snapshot" solution. The FileSystemWatcher i not really what i'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Who upvoted the @David comment? Polling a folder at regular intervals is an appalling idea when FileSystemWatcher is available. Commenting on a question where you start "I don't actually know..." is even worse. If you don't know, don't comment!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). It provides methods to do exactly what you want to do:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
{
    Path = stringWithYourPath,
    Filter = "*.txt"
};
// Add event handlers for all events you want to handle
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
// Activate the watcher
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true
```

Where OnChanged is an event handler:

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Check out the FileSystemWatcher class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

You'll find a complete example towards the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 4):

> **FileSystemWatcher** is a very powerful component, which allows us to
>   connect to the directories and watch for specific changes within them,
>   such as creation of new files, addition of subdirectories and renaming
>   of files or subdirectories. This makes it possible to easily detect
>   when certain files or directories are created, modified or deleted. It
>   is one of the members of System.IO namespace.

[**Full Tutorial Here**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mokhtarb2005/FSWatcherMB12052005063103AM/FSWatcherMB.aspx)

It has events and theyare

- Created - raised whenever a directory or file is created.
- Deleted - raised whenever a directory or file is deleted.
- Renamed - raised whenever the name of a directory or file is changed.
- Changed - raised whenever changes are made to the size, system attributes, last write time, last access time or NTFS security permissions of a directory or file.

Answer (score 0):

For "snapshot" solution is possible to use this library https://github.com/igorcrevar/Directory-Snapshot-Difference-Csharp